# Is code duplication a sufficient reason to extract a method...?

Tags: design-patterns, language-agnostic, architecture

...when the extracted method would suffer from low cohesion (not forming a good abstraction and having a poor name)?

For example, what name would you give to a following method?

```
private void foobar() {
    Server.checkAllowedDeviceCount(socketAction._sess.getDeviceID();
    socketAction.registerSession();
    socketAction._sess.runApplication();
}
```

This is a *possible* duplicate of another question of mine: [To DRY or not to DRY? On avoiding code duplication and retaining cohesion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4178128/212832) - or my desperate way of getting some suggestions from more experienced programmers out there (hope you forgive me). Please check the above link - it contains code which the the sample I'm presenting here is based on.

Comment: Where's the duplication? I can't see it in your example; and I'm not sure how relevant renaming the method is to method extraction? Sure, when you extract code into a new method you have to name it - but isn't your question more about duplication being sufficient reason?

Answer (score 1):

I build [code clone detectors](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Clone).  Often I see multiple sets of code A B C P Q found as clones, where A B C are conceptually coherent, and P Q are conceptually coherent, but ABC and PQ are unrelated.  A clone detector (or an uneducated-about-your-code reader) will see the same sequence as clones.  Yes, you could try to make a bad abstraction FOOBAR out of A B C P Q, but from a principled reader's point of view, your are better making just A B C inyo an abstraction, and then considering what to do about the P Q clones.

I don't know if this applies in your situation, since all your calls *are* socketactions (A B C?) and I'm unfamiliar with your interface.

Answer (score 0):

If the duplication was "bad" then yes I'd consider extracting it, but you'll always want to balance this with other concerns.

Also, according to [Extract Method Refactoring (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0s21cwxk.aspx), there are 4 reaons to extract a method, and duplication is one of them.

The others (as stated on the linked article) are:

- Encourages best coding practices by emphasizing discrete, reusable methods.
- Encourages self-documenting code through good organization.  When descriptive names are used, high-level methods can read more like a series of comments.
- Encourages the creation of finer-grained methods to simplify overriding.

Comment: Full code sample with duplicated code can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4178128/212832), but I guess you've already seen it since you answered the other question as well. I've read it somewhere, can't really remember where right now (I'll try to find a reference) that it only makes sense to extract a method when the name reveals its intent, so that you don't have to check the implementation to see what's happening. Hence my question - would you trade readability for reduced duplication?

Comment: I think one probably shouldn't just automatically extract method when one sees duplication - sometimes it would be better to restructure the whole thing until extraction seems like the most natural thing to do - if you know what I'm trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

After taking a look at your "To DRY..." question, I think this function should be extracted -- the duplication is enough of a smell to justify it.

Trying to infer the purpose of the SocketAction class from the inner classes you've shown in that question, it seems like StartSession is a reasonable name for this function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the key, if you had to change one of the duplicates (to fix a bug, or add a feature,) would you also have to change the others? If the answer is "yes" then combine them into one function.

I notice too, that all three lines of your function deal with a socketAction, and `this`/`self` is not referenced at all. That suggests that this method should be part of socketAction's class.